# How to watch only main sass file on phpstorm?

Tags: sass, phpstorm, file-watcher

I have a css structure where I have a folder with vendors, other with modules, other with framework, and on the root sass I have my main file which imports all the other sass files form the other folders.

How can I set the file watcher on PHPStorm to only watch that specific main.scss file??

This is what I have on PHPStorm file watcher.

Arguments:

```
    cache --update $FileName$:$FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Working directory:

```
    $FileDir$
```

Output paths to refresh:

```
    $FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Comment: "Track root only" option .. or just hard code your master file name in "arguments" field.

Comment: It's ok for you to restructure your sass/css paths?

Answer (score 1):

yesterday i had the same problem and gave up and told myself that i have to sleep over it so i can craft new ideas

The magic word here is **Partials** > [SASS Guide: Partials](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4)

You have to extend all your non-main files with an underscore so your file vendors.sass for example would look like this: _vendors.sass. The File Watcher now knows that he can skip this file since it's a partial. The main file is then the only one which doesn't come with an underscore :)

Beneath i show you my folder structure and the configurations for the watcher.

```
├── css
│   ├── sass
│   │   ├── _cookie.sass
│   │   ├── _farben.sass
│   │   ├── _navi.sass
│   │   ├── _schriften.sass
│   │   ├── _sidebar.sass
│   │   ├── _typo.sass
│   │   └── style.sass
│   ├── style.css
```

And this is the configuration for phpstorm to tell the app where to save the (compressed) output-file:

**Arguments:**

```
--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileParentDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css --style compressed
```

**Working directory:**

```
$fileDir$
```

**Output paths to refresh:**

```
$FileParentDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

I think that you maybe already have solved this problem, since your question is more than five months old. But in my case i was blind to see that this was a simple sass-thing. So hopefully no one needs to struggle for a solution like me in the future!

Cheers

Comment: Partials have nothing to do with the question being asked.  The vast majority of libraries out there, including the ones the OP is likely using, exclusively use partials.  I don't know anything about phpstorm, but Sass will still watch for changes in partial files when watching an entire directory.

Comment: When you activate the watcher in pstorm it generates out of every .sass/.scss file a .css file, OP was asking how to config the app in a way so only the main file gets processed. Of course the watcher walks through all sass files but what the OP wanted is that only the main file with all linked partials only get processed.

Comment: But you're sitting here assuming that the OP is *not* using partials, when it's almost certain that they are (if not in their own code, they almost certainly are in 3rd party libraries).

Comment: i guess this is a missunderstanding, actually i know that she is using partials . i understood her question like this: she uses a main file with a lot of @import and every time she edits a partial which gets importet the main file needs to get processed not the single partials. (Sry for my limited english-skills)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with PHPStorm (and presumably WebStorm).
*Note: I am using version 2018.3*

To transpile just a single "main" file, you need to configure the PHPStorm File Watcher **Scope**:

1. Open PHPStorm Preferences (on a Mac, `command comma`)
2. Search for `File Watchers` and edit them.
3. Find your `SCSS` file watcher (presumably this will work with other watchers) and edit it.
4. In the configuration window, click the 3-dot icon that is to the right of the "Scopes" dropdown.
5. In the "Scopes" window, click the `+` icon to add a new scope.
6. From the "Add Scope" dropdown, choose `Local Scope`.
7. When prompted, enter the descriptive name of the scope (something like `Theme File Only`)
8. Now you should be in the "Scope" window (see screenshot).  In the file explorer section in the middle, expand the tree and find the file you'd like to transpile.
9. Click the file (you can choose multiple if appropriate), and click the `Include` button to the right.
10. Click `Apply` then `OK`.
11. In your file watcher dialog, in the "Scope" dropdown, ensure that the newly added scope (named `Them File Only` or similar) is selected.  Click `Apply` then `OK`.

At this point, the IDE will only watch, and transpile, the specific file(s) selected.

[image: PHPStorm Watcher "Scopes" Window]

Comment: While this is working you need to keep in mind that to apply changes in the partial files to the global .css, you will always have to resave the global .scss file. If I understand the requiremts correctly, the op doesn't want to write css files for partial files but still watch changes to them. In this case checking "Track only root files" should do the trick.